# Я создаю сайт с авторизацией. Но у меня ошибка. Код ниже:

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
**forms.py
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    from .models import AdvUser
    class ChangeUserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email address')
        class Meta:
            model = AdvUser
            fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'send_messages')
    class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email address')
        password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())
        password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password(repeatedly)', widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text='Enter the same password again to verify')
        def clean_password1(self):
            password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
            if password1:
                password_validation.validate_password(password1)
            return password1
        def clean(self):
            super().clean()
            password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
            password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                errors = {'password2': ValidationError('The entered passwords do not match', code='password_mismatch')}
                raise ValidationError(errors)
        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super().save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.is_active = False
            user.is_activated = False
            if commit:
                user.save()
            #user_registrated.send(RegisterUserForm, instance=user)
            return user
        class Meta:
            model = AdvUser
            fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'send_messages')**** 
urls.py
path('accounts/register/done/', RegisterDoneView.as_view(), name='register_done'),
path('accounts/register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register'),

views.py
class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    model = AdvUser
    template_name = 'main/register_user.html'
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:register_done')

models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class AdvUser(AbstractUser):
    is_activated = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Did you activate?')
    send_messages = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Notify me of new comments?')

    class Meta:
        pass
```

File "C:\Users\User\Documents\EndTermProject\kinokorik\main\forms.py", line 28, in clean     password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1'] KeyError: 'password1'

Comment: Непонятен текст ошибки?

Comment: password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']  KeyError: 'password1'

Answer (score 0):

Уберите кавычки в запросе элемента словаря. Вы пытатесь использовать имя переменной вместо ее значния

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError: 'password1'` означает, что ключ `password1` отсутствует в словаре `self.cleaned_data`, поскольку поле `Password` в формуляре не было заполнено. По умолчанию формы в Django не заполняют отсутствующие значения в полях, так что проверяй сам на присутствие значения `password1`:

```
password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1', None)
if password1 is None:
    raise ValidationError('No password given')
password_validation.validate_password(password1)
```

Кроем того, дефолтные значения полей формуляра можно задать с помощью `initial` при создании объекта, к примеру

```
form = RegisterUserForm(initial={'password1': 'defaultpw'})
```

но для пароля это имеет мало смысла.